# Convergence of series 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine wether these series are convergent:

1) $$\sum_{l=5}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{l^2} + \frac {2}{l^3}\right)$$

$$ \left(\frac{1}{l^2} + \frac {2}{l^3}\right)=\frac {l^3+l^2}{l^5} > \frac {1}{l^2}$$

Does this way works for the comparison test?

I don't think because the minorant is convergent, am I right?

Could I do it by this way:

$$ a_l:=\frac{1}{l^2} \text{ and } b_l:=\frac {2}{l^3} $$

and then say that both series $a_l$ and $b_l$ are convergent $p$-series so that the sum also have to be convergent,
 is that correct or is this only allowed for multiplication with series?


2) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac {1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$$

With the CT:

$$\left\lvert\frac {1}{n^2+n+1}\right\rvert < \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Because of the harmonic $p$-seriew:

 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
 which converges,

 so 2) is convergent.

3) $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\frac {4m^3-2m^2-m+5}{m^7+3m^2-2m}\right)$$

 
Here I have the same problem because I found a series which is majorant which is smaller then the series 3)..

My idea would be to multiply 3) by $1/b_k$ and look at the limit.

Comment: too many questions on same post :((!!

Comment: perhaps.. I thougth I should write the 3 series because my questions are quite connected for the 3 series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3), you should see that the summand behaves as $4/m^4$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$, so it converges by the comparison test.

Comment: So I can neglect the other terms,in the same way as if I would regard the limit of a sequence?

Comment: Yes, the other terms are necessarily smaller.

Comment: then if it works for 3), it also works for 1) and i can say that it's convergent because "1)" = $1/l^2$ and that converges?

Comment: I suppose that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$1) \sum \limits_{l=5}^\infty (\frac{1}{l^2} + \frac {2}{l^3})$

This is a sum of two  [P-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) $ - \text{ something }$ with $p>1$, since both converges, it should.

$2) 
\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^2+n+1}$
As you reasoned

$3) \sum \limits_{m=1}^\infty (\frac {4m^3-2m^2-m+5}{m^7+3m^2-2m}) < \sum \limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac {4m^3-2m^2-m+5}{m^7} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \frac{4}{m^4} - \frac{2}{m^5} - \frac{1}{m^6} + \frac{5}{m^7} \right)$

Comment: Thanks now I see it in 3) so to do the comparison test of a fraction with 2 polynoms, I always have to neglect the other terms from lower degree in the denominator and after this I only have regard the different serie terms with the p-test?

Comment: @phil yep!! that's the idea ,,, whenever they get big $n\to \infty $ the term with the highest power will be dominate others ... so, you can do it.